# Is this the correct expected output of program?

Tags: java

I need help determining if this is the right output of the problem below.  I wrote what I think to be correct but I would like some verification.  First time posting here so I apologize if I did anything incorrectly.

Mexico's population is 62 million and is growing at the annual 
rate of 7%. The United States' current population is 280 million and is
growing at the annual rate of 2%. If these two countries were to
maintain their current rates of growth, in how many years will Mexico's
population be more than half that of the United States? Your program
should answer this question.

This is what I wrote

```
public class Population
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int year = 0;

    int mexicoPop = 62000000;
    double mexRate = mexicoPop * .07;

    int usPop = 280000000;
    double usRate = usPop * .02;

    int usHalf = 140000000;
    for(int i=mexicoPop; i<=usHalf; i++)
    {
        mexicoPop += mexRate;
        usPop += usRate;
        usHalf = usPop/2;
        year++;         
    }
    System.out.println("Mexico's population will be more than half of the US in " + year + " years");

}
}
```

I get an output of 1011741824 but have no idea if that's actually the correct number given the math problem.  If I knew the number it would be a lot easier to tell if my program is correct. Can anyone assist with this. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: You don't have a calculator?

Comment: (I will say that 1011741824 years seems like a really long time.)

Comment: Is this a math question or a programming question?

Comment: (FWIW I get something closer to a couple decades. You're not recalculating enough.)

Comment: Ok I will take a break and come back to it with a fresh mind. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Good idea. I'd recommend doing a few iterations by hand, like on paper, without looking at your code, to understand what calculations need to be done and when. It's easy to sanity-check a simple algorithm like this by looking at some output. What would the populations be after one year? After two years? Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically you'll have to do something like this for the years until

> Mexico's population be more than half that of the United States?

```
int numberOfYears = 0;
while(mexicoPop < usPop / 2)
{
    mexicoPop = mexicoPop + mexicoPop * .07; // since the RHS would be changing every year
    usPop = usPop + usPop * .02;    
    numberOfYears++; 
}
System.out.println(numberOfYears);
```

Comment: I'd recommend doing your own homework next time. And instead of taking someone else's solution, which IMO shouldn't have been directly provided, taking the time to think it through.